# PHP MySQL Syntax Error on Select

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I am trying to Save an Email Address into my database and i am getting the following error

```
  include 'db.php';
  echo $email = $accounts['username'];
  $date = date ("Y-m-d H:m:s");

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where email = $email", $conn) or die($myQuery."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
  $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

  if ($num_rows == 0) {
    $query_string = "INSERT INTO users (id, email, created)
                                        VALUES (null, '$email', '$date')";

      if (mysql_query($query_string, $conn)) {
        echo "$name inserted<br/>";
      } else {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
        echo "Error inserting $email<br/>";
      }

  } else {
    echo "$email exists<br/>";
  }
```

Error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@mink7.com' at line 1

Comment: Have you checked the query on the line where the error is reported? Did you inspect it for any errors?

Comment: its coming at the Select Query where i am trying to check if the email exists in the database

Comment: I know that's where it is coming from; have you tried to read that query and at least try to find an error in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

marcochiesi has the right answer, but I would suggest mysql_real_escape_string to help prevent an SQL injection attack as well:

```
"SELECT * FROM users where email = '". mysql_real_escape_string($email)."'"
```

**Update**

FYI, if you don't put the quote's around the information you are constraining, MySQL is expecting it to be a column.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :) i am getting the email from GOOGLE API should i still escape it ?

Comment: short answer yes! You never know who is crawling your site, sniffing your traffic, etc. To be safe, it is always a good idea to escape SQL queries, no matter what the deployment or implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You should quote $email in the first SQL statement:

`"SELECT * FROM users where email = '$email'"`